# Best way to represent single valued time events with gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following which is event data from an electronic sensor. In a nutshell, anytime the sensor has an event, it logs a value of `1` with the timestamp.  I can plot this with gnuplot via `plot "/tmp/data" using 1:3 with points` which gives a bunch of dots (at Y1) grouped at the time intervals. It seems like there could be a better way to represent this data. How would you do plot this?

`2016-10-12 21:41:54 1
2016-10-12 21:42:00 1
2016-10-12 21:42:09 1
2016-10-12 21:42:14 1
2016-10-12 21:42:25 1
2016-10-12 21:42:31 1
2016-10-12 21:42:36 1
2016-10-12 21:42:41 1
2016-10-12 21:51:35 1
2016-10-12 21:51:41 1
2016-10-12 22:01:03 1`

[image]

Comment: Well, that depends mainly on what you want to show with the data. What is the meaning of the event? What should the resulting plot tell the user?

Comment: Thanks. The sensor is connected to a network route. Each time there is a disconnect detected on the route, the value on the sensor goes high. I'd like a graph which shows the frequency of these events over a given time span. This is what I have currently (pic added to original post). Perhaps this "horizontal point cloud" is the only way to represent the limited data set.  It just seems like this could be done better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to plot the frequency of the events, than you should also calculate the frequency (`smooth frequency`) and plot them as histogram. The easiest way of binning in your case would be to skip the seconds when reading the time columns:

```
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
set xdata time
set yrange [0:*]
set format x "%H:%M"
set ylabel "Disconnects per minute"
set boxwidth 60 absolute
set style fill solid noborder
plot "data.dat" using 1:3 with boxes smooth frequency notitle
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the absolute best way:
`plot '/tmp/data' using 3 with impulses lw 2`

Answer (score 0):

Old question, I know, but I like the lollipop graphs, which you can emulate in gnuplot with *impulse* and *point*.

See: https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781849517249/1/ch01lvl1sec24/making-an-impulse-plot

(It is toward the end of the article. The best looking lollipops I've seen are not multicolored like they have in the article, but you can search for examples of what matches your taste.)

[image]

Image from here: https://datavizproject.com/data-type/lollipop-chart/